# Python on WSL2 Ubuntu launch.json args

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging, wsl-2

I'm using VSCode: 1.62.3 with Windows_NT x64 Version 10.0.22000 and Ubuntu on WSL2.
I have prepared a main.py file with this code:

```
import argparse

argumnet = argparse.ArgumentParser()

argumnet.add_argument('--name', type=str, required=True)

parser = argumnet.parse_args()

print(f'Ciao {parser.name}')
```

and a launch.json file with this configuration:

```
{
    // Usare IntelliSense per informazioni sui possibili attributi.
    // Al passaggio del mouse vengono visualizzate le descrizioni degli attributi esistenti.
    // Per altre informazioni, visitare: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Debug",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": ["--name", "Marco"],
        }
    ]
}
```

and when I start the debugging or the execution the main.py file was executed withouth the args.

Answer (score 0):

In the Linux `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`, add this line:

```
"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true
```